# Count number of occurrence of character for each file (first line only)

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that contains a bunch of csv files.

I would like to make a Powershell script that is able to read the first line of each file in that folder and count the number of occurence of a specific character within that line (a semicolon in my case).

The desired output file would be :

```
File_1 : 6 --number of semicolons in the 1st line of the 1st file
File_2 : 8  --number of semicolons in the 1st line of the 2nd file
File_3 : 13  --number of semicolons in the 1st line of the 3rd file
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break this down as:

- Discover all the files
- For each of them:

  - Read first line
  - Count semicolons
  - Output file name + count

```
# Discover the files
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\folder\*.csv

foreach($file in $csvFiles){
  # Read first line
  $firstLine = $file |Get-Content -TotalCount 1

  # Remove anything that's NOT a semicolon - resulting length is the count
  $firstLine = $firstLine -replace '[^;]'

  # output file name and count
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Filename = $file.Name
    Count = $firstline.Length
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You only forgot to overwrite the value of $firstLine otherwise it will give the the length of the whole line. It worked for me like this : $firstLine  = $firstLine -replace '[^;]'

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seemed a bit unnecessarily complicated so here is a Powershell one liner:

```
Get-Childitem -Filter *.csv | % {$_ | Add-Member -Name Count -MemberType NoteProperty -Value ([regex]::Matches((Get-Content $_.Name -TotalCount 1), ':').Count); $_} | Select Name, Count
```

Comment: It is counting the occurrence for the whole file. I only needed it to be counted for the first line of the file.

Comment: Sorry missed the first line bit - have updated my answer.

Comment: Good effort, but your one-liner is not a true one-liner, because of that semicolon involved. Sure, it's all on one line, but well, you know, the semicolon is a terminator in this use case. --- https://mikefrobbins.com/2019/02/07/whats-a-powershell-one-liner-not-a-powershell-one-liner/ --- https://powershellstation.com/2016/07/31/you-dont-need-semicolons-in-multi-line-hashtable-literals/ --- if you tried to splat what you did, you'd have to do this. $(([regex]::Matches((Get-Content $_.Name -TotalCount 1), ':').Count); $_), or it would show as an error in the ISE/VSCode.